# Is there any way to convince Apple Mail to write its configuration as text Plist files instead of binary?

Tags: mail.app, macos, plist

I'd like to revision-control my mail configuration (both the preferences and the mailbox rules -- especially the latter) but Mail insists on rewriting its preferences as binary plist files as soon as it opens. I'd like to have it keep them in text or XML format, which would allow me to keep them in revision control in a meaningful way. Yes, I could keep them as binaries, but those are awful and result in a lot of ugly changesets.

Comment: Which revision control system? There may be a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but you could use plutil to convert the binary plist to XML and keep the results in your revision control system.

Comment: git. So, presumably, it'd be possible to do it with a pre-commit and post-update hook? That might be interesting...

Comment: However, I can't see a way to do this from the git hooks docs at http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html; maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I would keep the XML files somewhere and write an install/build script to convert them to binary and to install them in Preferences etc.